# Why is "sudo su" slow without ALL=(root) in /etc/sudoers?

Tags: linux, sudo, su, suse, sles

I have had this weird issue on a SLES 12 Server.

**Info**:

- We have lots of application users like for example applusr01, applusr02, ...
- We have a special user which has sudoers rights to run commands as given application users. (central_user)

Suddenly after a maintenance weekend even simple commands run with "sudo su" would take a long time.

**Example**:

```
central_user@server001:/home/central_user : time sudo su applusr01 -c whoami
applusr01
real    0m1.624s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.011s
```

**/etc/sudoers**:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

**/etc/sudoers.d/central_user**:

```
central_user ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/su
```

**Question**:
When I add the following to the /etc/sudoers , the runtime goes down to normal values again.
**But why**?
And if I add it to /etc/sudoers.d/central_user, the runtime does not improve.
**Is there something I am missing with the sudoers behaviour**?

```
central_user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su
```

**Example**:

```
central_user@server001:/home/central_user : time sudo su applusr01 -c whoami
applusr01
real    0m0.029s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.014s
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the act of changing `/etc/sudoers` and not simply the time required to go back far enough in `wtmp` to find the previous root login time? On systems that get a lot of logins (usually because of automated file transfers etc.) I find that the first login after a long absence can be really slow, because there are just so many login entries to go through before the system finds the time of the previous login. After one successful login it will be fast again, because then the previous login entry will again be quite recent.

Comment: Alternatively, does your `/etc/sudoers` and/or `/etc/sudoers.d/*` include anything that requires DNS resolving? If so, make sure those will either resolve or fail fast. Wouldn't be the first time someone has accidentally blocked DNS access at the firewall, and because firewalls generally DROP packets instead of REJECTing, blocking DNS means suffering the full timeout delays in every lookup.

Comment: Or user lookups changed with the "maintenance "

Comment: It is most definitely the act of changing /etc/sudoers
When I add:
central_user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su

The runtime  goes down as described. And if I remove the line, it goes up again.
And I cannot spot anything which requires DNS resolving in the /etc/sudoers. Unless it´s maybe some LDAP thing? Does it maybe check in LDAP if the user is authorized for the sudoers?

Comment: @Miller-STGT probably if you are not caching ldap stuff via something like nscd.

Comment: @jordanm That makes sense! ALL=(root) means that I will access /bin/su as root which is a local user in that case. Otherwise I will look up through nscd in LDAP which would explain that high runtime. Does this make sense?